# How to control data when Payment gate way go to the notify URL in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, payment-gateway

I integrate the payfast payment gateway and it is working properly but I

want to control data when it goes to the notify url before success.

Actually I want to update payment status,to get the notify value.I am new in

Symfony.

I integrate the payment gate way using controller function

```
/**
            * @Route("/api/pay/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, defaults={"id" = 1})
            * @Method("GET")
        */
        public function pay($id, Request $request)
        {

            $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Order');
            $orders = $repository->findById($id);
            foreach ($orders as $order);

            $firstname = $order->getFirstname();
            $lastname = $order->getLastname();
            $email = $order->getEmail();

            $item_name = $order->getDiagnostic();



            $item_description = $item_name . '_' .$order->getComfort() . '_' .$order->getSize();

            $cartTotal = 200;

            $error = 'https://api.lunaonline.co.za/api/pay/error';
            $success = 'https://api.lunaonline.co.za/api/pay/success';
            $notify = 'https://api.lunaonline.co.za/api/pay/notify';

            $data = array(

            'merchant_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXX',
            'merchant_key' => 'XXXXXXXXX',
            'return_url' => $success,
            'cancel_url' => $error,
            'notify_url' => $notify,
            // Buyer details
            'name_first' => $firstname,
            'name_last'  =>  $lastname,
            'email_address'=> $email,

            // Transaction details
            'm_payment_id' => $id, //Unique payment ID to pass through to notify_url
            'amount' => number_format( sprintf( "%.2f", $cartTotal ), 2, '.', '' ), //Amount in ZAR
            'item_name' => $item_name,
            'item_description' => $item_description
            );

            $pfOutput="";
            foreach( $data as $key => $val )
            {
                if(!empty($val))
                {
                    $pfOutput .= $key .'='. urlencode( trim( $val ) ) .'&';
                }
            }
            // Remove last ampersand
            $getString = substr( $pfOutput, 0, -1 );
            if( isset( $passPhrase ) )
            {
                $getString .= '&passphrase='. urlencode( trim( $passPhrase ) );
            }   
            $data['signature'] = md5( $getString );


            return $this->render('pay/pay.html.twig', $data);
        }
```

when it goes to the notify URL i used function

```
/**
            * @Route("/api/pay/notify")
            * @Method("POST")
        */
        public function payNotify(Request $request)
        {


        }
```

How to get the data which is posted by the payment gateway and I want to update

staus field into database.so I want to get the status value which is posted by

payfast gateway.HOw to get this array.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here in the documentation](http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html)

You can use the `Request $request` object to find out which params are returned to your application

```
public function payNotify(Request $request)
{
   $params = $request->request->all();
}
```